# Laravel Http Client with proxy working only on first request

Tags: php, laravel, http, proxy

1. Make a get request to some URL using the `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http` with a proxy setup;
2. The request goes through the proxy and hits the destination server. I can see the IP received belongs to the proxy and not to my machine. (Everything working fine so far);
3. Make that same request again;
4. The IP received by the destination server belongs to my machine. The proxy is not working anymore.

See the tinker output:

```
my-aws-docker-user@fb14363368ff:/var/www/html$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.10.4 (PHP 7.4.10 — cli) by Justin Hileman

>>> $credentials = "http://54.234.XXX.XX:808";
=> "http://54.234.XXX.XX:808"

>>> \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::withOptions(['proxy' => $credentials, 'debug' => true])->get('https://api.ipify.org/')->body();

* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x560ff2ad7d30)
* Expire in 150000 ms for 2 (transfer 0x560ff2ad7d30)
*   Trying 54.234.XXX.XX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x560ff2ad7d30)
* Connected to 54.234.XX.XX (54.234.XXX.XX) port 808 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to api.ipify.org:443
> CONNECT api.ipify.org:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.ipify.org:443
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< Proxy-agent: CCProxy
<
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed!
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard; CN=*.ipify.org
*  start date: Jan 24 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 23 23:59:59 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.ipify.org" matched cert's "*.ipify.org"
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.ipify.org
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.64.0 PHP/7.4.10

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Cowboy
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Vary: Origin
< Date: Tue, 29 Sep 2020 20:10:22 GMT
< Content-Length: 13
< Via: 1.1 vegur
<
* Connection #0 to host 54.234.XXX.XX left intact

=> "54.234.XXX.XX" // This is my proxy IP
```

The first request works good. Now performing the same one in the same tinker session (arrow up + enter):

```
>>> \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::withOptions(['proxy' => $credentials, 'debug' => true])->get('https://api.ipify.org/')->body();

* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 150000 ms for 2 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 3 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 3 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 3 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 3 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 5 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 5 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 6 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 6 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 8 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 7 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 7 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 8 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 8 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 8 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 16 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 10 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 10 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 16 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 11 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 11 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 16 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 14 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 14 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 15 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
*   Trying 23.21.203.47...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 74977 ms for 3 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x560ff2addc90)
* Connected to api.ipify.org (23.21.203.47) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard; CN=*.ipify.org
*  start date: Jan 24 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 23 23:59:59 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.ipify.org" matched cert's "*.ipify.org"
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.ipify.org
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.64.0 PHP/7.4.10

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Cowboy
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Vary: Origin
< Date: Tue, 29 Sep 2020 20:11:26 GMT
< Content-Length: 11
< Via: 1.1 vegur
<
* Connection #0 to host api.ipify.org left intact

=> "3.92.XX.XXX" // This is my instance IP
```

- The application is running in a docker container hosted in a EC2 Instance on AWS;
- The problem seems to occur only on AWS;
- The proxy server is working fine. We tried Squid Cache Proxy and CCProxy and both have the same issue;
- Performing a cURL request from the docker container on AWS also works (see logs below).

```
my-aws-docker-user@fb14363368ff:/var/www/html$ curl -x http://54.234.XXX.XX:808 -L https://api.ipify.org/ -v
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55abb8f38f50)
*   Trying 54.234.XXX.XX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55abb8f38f50)
* Connected to 54.234.XXX.XX (54.234.XXX.XX) port 808 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to api.ipify.org:443
> CONNECT api.ipify.org:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.ipify.org:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< Proxy-agent: CCProxy
<
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed!
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard; CN=*.ipify.org
*  start date: Jan 24 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 23 23:59:59 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.ipify.org" matched cert's "*.ipify.org"
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.ipify.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Cowboy
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Vary: Origin
< Date: Tue, 29 Sep 2020 20:32:25 GMT
< Content-Length: 13
< Via: 1.1 vegur
<
* Connection #0 to host 54.234.XXX.XX left intact
54.234.XXX.XX // This is my proxy IP
```

Comment: It might help if you show the code that actually make these reqeusts

Comment: Is [`TrustedProxy`](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) relevant to this at all? Just starting to investigate...

Comment: The code executed is in my question. You can copy and paste to reproduce (you will need a proxy server). Problem seems to happen only on AWS. In my case, is a container running in a EC2 instance.

Comment: The trust proxy is indeed something to look at. I already setup the trusted proxy as Laravel says to work with AWS Load Balancers. But thanks for the tip, will look at that deeper